# Dumping local variables in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, debugging

I would like to write a function that will find all local variables and save them to disc. Later on, I want to load these variables and call/debug function from which the variables were saved. The goal is to speedup debugging of functions that are deep inside of my code.

I have used similar technique in Matlab, which allows to save whole workspace and later load it and continue. Can I use similar/relevant technique in C++?

Comment: What are you trying to save, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

You're searching for a [reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) mechanism.

In C++ there isn't any reflector facility to enumerate variables, so you can not do it like Matlab.

You should make a data structure and add variables manually in the code. Then do whatever you want.

In practices programmers will use these steps:

To Save:

- Open a file
- Write values of variable1, variable2, ... into the file
- Close the file

To load:

- Open the file
- Read variable1, variable2, ... from file and store them to corresponding variables
- Close the file

Comment: I see. Would it be possible to save a block of memory in stack that corresponds local variables?

Comment: If you know the address of that block in runtime, then yes you can write it a sequence of bytes into a file, but I'm not sure it will help you in debugging or not.

Comment: Sounds like you want to generate a core dump and open it in a debugger. Getting just the stack state probably won't be too helpful without more context and the accompanying source & object code to interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

What about the call history?  What about the values in registers?  Do you want to resume at the first line of the function or some other line.

You could try writing the stack, but that only works if no variables have constructors or pointers to malloc'd memory.

You can use setjmp() to get all the values in registers and longjmp() to restore them.

If you are on Windows, you can look into the DbgHelp API. It may have a way to enumerate all local variables.